# Winforms show taskbar icon when form icon is hidden

Tags: c#, winforms

My application launches several forms that have their parent set to the "Main Form". 
The Main Form has a Form Icon and `ShowIcon = true`.
My "child" forms all have an Icon set as well but have `ShowIcon = false`. My desired effect is that it shows the icon in the taskbar but not in the form itself. Currently, it's showing a generic windows icon instead.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think so.  I think any form in the taskbar requires an icon.  Child forms usually have the `ShowInTaskbar` property set to false.